# Error when using KnockoutObservableArray in TypeScript

Tags: knockout.js, typescript1.5

I have the following code:

```
class IndexViewModel {
    projects: KnockoutObservableArray<Project>;

    constructor() {
        this.projects = ko.observableArray<Project>([]);
    }

    filteredList: KnockoutComputed<Project[]> = ko.computed(() => {
        var elements = ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.projects(), (item: Project) => {
           //do something
        });
        //return something
        })
    }
```

But when I load the page, I get a JavaScript error, that says, 
`TypeError: _this.projects is not a function index-ViewModel_test.js`

The rendered JavaScript for that part is,

```
this.filteredList = ko.computed(function () {
            var elements = ko.utils.arrayFilter(_this.projects(), function (item) {
                //return something
            });
            //return something
        })
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the `projects` member was not yet defined when the `filteredList` was computed. Moving the computation in the constructor of the class solved my issue.
The code:

```
constructor() {
        this.projects = ko.observableArray<Project>([]);
        this.filteredList = ko.computed(() => {
            var elements = ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.projects(), (item: Project) => {
                //return something
            });
            //return something
        });
    }
```